# UITableViewRowAnimation as a block (instead of a row) animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

Is there anyway to make a UITableViewRowAnimation animate at the same time?

Such as, If I'm adding 4 rows to a TableView, animate the block of 4 rows rather than animating both row individually?

Snippet, tutorial for custom animation etc are welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways [as described in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html):

> **Batch Insertion, Deletion, and Reloading of Rows and Sections**
>
> The UITableView class allows you to insert, delete, and reload a group
>   of rows or sections at one time, animating the operations
>   simultaneously in specified ways. The eight methods shown in Listing
>   7-7 pertain to batch insertion and deletion. Note that you can call
>   these insertion and deletion methods outside of an animation block (as
>   you do in the data source method
>   tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: as discussed in
>   “Inserting and Deleting Rows in Editing Mode”).
>
> Listing 7-7  Batch insertion and deletion methods

```
- (void)beginUpdates;
- (void)endUpdates;

- (void)insertSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;

- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation: (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation: (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

Comment: Yeah, however, the animation is -each row- being animated, I had prefer the -block of new rows- to animate